# Angular 9 Universal - Running Error: can not read property 'type' of undefined - TokenStream

Tags: angular, rxjs, server-side-rendering, angular-universal

talents.

I am working on Angular 9 project.

My original project was Angular 9, Node.js, Express project.

I converted it to Angular Universal.
[image]
When I run "npm run dev:ssr", I see this kind of error.

This is my package.json.

```
"@angular-redux/store": "^10.0.0",
"@angular/animations": "^9.1.4",
"@angular/cdk": "^9.2.2",
"@angular/common": "~9.1.4",
"@angular/compiler": "~9.1.4",
"@angular/core": "~9.1.4",
"@angular/forms": "~9.1.4",
"@angular/material": "^9.2.2",
"@angular/platform-browser": "~9.1.4",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~9.1.4",
"@angular/platform-server": "~9.1.4",
"@angular/router": "~9.1.4",
"@nguniversal/express-engine": "^9.1.1",
"@ngx-translate/core": "^12.1.2",
"@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^4.0.0",
"express": "^4.17.1",
"graphql-js-client": "^0.12.0",
"jquery": "^3.5.1",
"js-base64": "^3.6.0",
"localstorage-polyfill": "^1.0.1",
"lodash": "^4.17.20",
"moment": "^2.29.1",
"ngx-device-detector": "^2.0.1",
"ngx-slick-carousel": "^0.5.1",
"ngx-toastr": "^12.0.1",
"node-fetch": "^2.6.1",
"npm-run-all": "^4.1.5",
"redux": "^4.0.5",
"redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.8",
"redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
"redux-observable": "^1.2.0",
"rxjs": "~6.5.4",
"rxjs-compat": "^6.6.3",
"slick-carousel": "^1.8.1",
"tslib": "^1.10.0",
"zone.js": "~0.10.2"
```

I`d really appreciate it if anyone can help me.
Regards!

Comment: I had a similar issue when using ngx-sharebuttons. Turned out I forgot to import the package's required stylesheet: '"node_modules/ngx-sharebuttons/themes/modern.scss"' in angular.json file, or you can import that in src/styles.scss.

Answer (score 1):

I have got this error when i tied to use method **setProperty** in my Component

```
mrthod():void {
 document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--vh', `${vh}px`);
}
```

The best way I have found: to define if this method calls with SSR

AppModule:

```
@NgModule({
  ...
  providers: [{
    provide: 'isServer',
    useValue: false
  }],
  ...
})
```

AppServerModule:

```
@NgModule({
  ...
  providers: [{
    provide: 'isServer',
    useValue: true
  }],
  ...
})
```

Component:

```
constructor(
    @Inject('isServer') private isServer: boolean,
) {}

mrthod():void {
  if (!this.isServer) {
    document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--vh', `${vh}px`);
  }
}
```

It's going to be fixed in 16 version
https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/42170

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a little irrelevant for you, but I also ran into this problem.
And finding no solution, I tried to maintain and repair the library.

https://github.com/angular-redux2/store
https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular-redux2/store

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).